# Wedding Vows puzzle

Tags: general-topology, puzzle, knot-theory

My father came up with a puzzle and dared me to solve it. I could solve it by trial and error, but I rather want to solve it mathematically. It is the so called ["Wedding Vows puzzle"](http://people.mills.edu/jemartin/CS286/more-puzzles.html) where you have to get the two seperated rings together on one side.

But the problem is: I don't know how to start. I thought about interpreting the little piece of wood as a compact surface of genus $2$ by identifying the left hole with the right hole. Then I could think about the rope as a path on the surface. But how could I proceed?

Does anybody know how to solve it?

Comment: First google result to wedding vows puzzle solution : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImMue-rCmo4

Comment: Thank you, but I'm interrested in a more mathematical way of solving the puzzle.